# Execute Dynamic Entity in Database using Dapper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dapper

My user send dynamic entity from client-project so, I have to write methods like this

```
public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //string sql = "SELECT * FROM \"IdentityUsers\" WHERE \"NormalizedUserName\" = @NormalizedUserName;";
        //using (var connection =  _databaseConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync())
        //{
        //   connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<TUser>(sql,
        //        new { NormalizedUserName = normalizedUserName });
        //}
    }
```

My **IDatabaseConnectionFactory** class bind ConnectionString like below:

```
public interface IDatabaseConnectionFactory
{       
    Task<IDbConnection> CreateConnectionAsync();
}

public class ConnectionFactory : IDatabaseConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ConnectionFactory(string connectionString) => _connectionString = connectionString ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));

    public async Task<IDbConnection> CreateConnectionAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var connString =  new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString);
            await connString.OpenAsync();
            return connString;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how can I execute following query using generic-type entity **TUser**

```
  string sql = "SELECT * FROM \"IdentityUsers\" WHERE \"NormalizedUserName\" = @NormalizedUserName;";
    using (var connection =  _databaseConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync())
    {
       connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<TUser>(sql,
            new { NormalizedUserName = normalizedUserName });
    }
```

Note: **QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync** not found under connection here

Comment: if [`QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L113) isn't found, it sounds like you're missing `using Dapper;` at the top, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell no dear, using Dapper; present inside the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't awaiting the `CreateConnectionAsync`. Unfortunately it isn't obvious in this case, because `Task<T>` is disposable (so the `using` doesn't complain); try instead:

```cs
using (var connection = await _databaseConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync())
{
    var user = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<TUser>(sql,
         new { NormalizedUserName = normalizedUserName });
}
```

As a tip: the compiler output (against the original code) helps make this clear:

> Error CS1929  '`Task<IDbConnection>`' does not contain a definition for '`QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync`' and the best extension method overload '`SqlMapper.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<TUser>(IDbConnection, string, object, IDbTransaction, int?, CommandType?)`' requires a receiver of type '`IDbConnection`'

which tells us that:

- it found *some* `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync` method, but it wasn't usable, because
- the target expression is a `Task<IDbConnection>`, not an `IDbConnection`

---

As a side note: it is worth knowing that if you're only doing one operation with the connection, Dapper can deal with opening and closing the connection for you - which can help reduce the number of async/await operations. Consider, for example, if you had a `CreateClosedConnection()` method that **did not** open the connection, and thus had no need to be async; the following would still work:

```cs
using (var connection = _databaseConnectionFactory.CreateClosedConnection())
{
    var user = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<TUser>(sql,
         new { NormalizedUserName = normalizedUserName });
}
```

with Dapper dealing with the `await OpenAsync()` for you as part of the `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync`.